# Spring application: connect to AD proxy - OpenLDAP, make dnPrettyNormal accept user@domain.com format?

Tags: spring, configuration, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I try to authenticate users in my Spring MVC application. I have a Active Directory server inside my domain, but my web server is outside of the domain, so I'm forced to establish a OpenLDAP proxy server.

Firstly i have successfully tried to establish a connection inside my domain, so the application works fine and makes the authentication. Everything is ok... BUT

after reading hundreds of web sites (because of the new cn=conf configuration - not slap.conf, which is IMO very hard to lear since most of the websites describe the deprecated configuration) and forums I have finally configured the proxy server with a ldap backend so it works like a proxy. Not without any problems - it hangs after invoking the ldapsearch, but still it returns results.

The problem is that the ldapsearch for my configuration of OpenLDAP does not accept distinguished names with the user@domain.com notation... only  is acceptable... the log file says:

> Nov 13 14:24:52 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[19149]: conn=1001 op=0 do_bind
>   Nov 13 14:24:52 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[19149]: >>> dnPrettyNormal: 
>   Nov 13 14:24:52 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[19149]: conn=1001 op=0 do_bind: invalid dn (user@domain.com)
>   Nov 13 14:24:52 ip-10-0-0-121 slapd[19149]: send_ldap_result: conn=1001 op=0 p=3

so the >>> **dnPrettyNormal**:  is not acceptable but generated from my spring application...

I think there are two ways of solving it:

1. (Preffered by me) Setup the OpenLDAP to accept the notation with the 'at' (@) character....
2. Force the Spring application to send the  format... but how to do it?

My spring-security.xml:

```
    <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="domain.com" />
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389/" /> <!--fake IP-->
    <beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials"
        value="true" />
    <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions"
        value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="grantedAuthoritiesMapper"
    class="com.xxx.ActiveDirectoryGrantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
```

Could you please advise me how to solve my problem?

---

**SOLUTION / UPDATE:**

I have managed to setup the connection. Now I'm using a LdapAuthenticationProvider
instead of ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider.

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref='ldapProvider' />
</authentication-manager>

<!-- This bean points at the embedded directory server created by the ldap-server 
    element above -->
<beans:bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://xx.xx.xx.xx:389/dc=domain,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="java.naming.referral" value="ignore" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="userDn"
        value="CN=user,OU=group,dc=domain,dc=com" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="secret" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="ldapProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch">
                <beans:bean id="userSearch"
                    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="1"
                        value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
                    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                    <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:constructor-arg value="" />
            <beans:property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
            <beans:property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="ignorePartialResultException"
                value="true" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string `user@domain.com` is not a valid distinguished name. A [DN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514) is a comma-separated sequence of relative distinguished names (RDNs), each of which is an attributeType-attributeValue assertion of the form `type=value` where `type` is the attribute type (an OID or an alias for an OID, like `mail`). `mail=user@domain.com,dc=domain,dc=com` is a valid distinguished name. Correct the DN in your configuration to use a valid string. The problem has nothing to do with the '`@`' character.

Comment: Yes, I know that... but I don't know how to force Spring to send the real DN to OpenLDAP instead of user@domain.com which AD actually accepts. But thank you anyway :)